# pip3 install works, but then running the python script the module is not found

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm currently doing

```
pip3 install reportlab
```

and that works fine. However in my script I have a

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
```

Running my script results in a module reportlab not found. To run the script I am using python3 name_of_script.py, but python name_of_script.py also doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Doing a find on my Mac points the reportlab to: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/reportlab-3.5.2.dist-info

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of `python` installed?  Run the `pip` from the location of the one you want the package installed to :)

Comment: @sniperd I did but still getting this error:Requirement already satisfied: reportlab in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from reportlab) (5.2.0). This is when running pip3 install reportlab from inside /usr/local/bin